# Assertion Error during compiling Solidity

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smart-contract

I'm new to Solidity and as any new programmer stuck with error while compiling, so here is my code

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;
contract Inbox {
    string public msg;

    function Inbox(string initialMsg) public {
        msg = initialMsg;
    }

    function setMsg(string newMsg) public {
        msg = newMsg;
    }
}
```

here is compile.js file looks like

```
const path = require('path')
const fs = require('fs')
const solc = require('solc')

const inboxPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'contracts', 'Inbox.sol')
const source = fs.readFileSync(inboxPath, 'utf8')
console.log(solc.compile(source, 1))
```

[image: file structure]

[image: error message]

Hope someone also stuck with this problem and found a solution. Thank you before hand)))

Answer (score 0):

"msg" зарезервированное слово Solidity. Попробуйте изменить его на "my_msg" например.